Is there a way to restore a stacked diff?
I have created my own stacked diff with a few branches that contain changes, my stacked diff has been deleted, I have his branches, is there any way to restore the stacked diff?
I tried looking for a solution myself on the internet but I couldn't find one.

In a Git project, you'll find a .git folder which contains various metadata about your repository. Within this folder, there's a refs directory that includes a stacked subdirectory.
The stacked folder is where information about your stacked diffs is stored. Each stacked diff has its own folder, and within these folders, you'll find JSON files. These JSON files represent the branches created by the stacked diff workflow.
To better understand how this works, you can set up a test project:

Create a new Git repository
Implement a stacked diff workflow
Create two or more branches from your stacked diff

By examining the resulting folder structure and JSON files in the .git/refs/stacked directory, you'll gain insights into how stacked diffs are represented. This knowledge can then be applied to manage and work with stacked diffs in your main project.
